# WHILE statement not recognizing declared variable

Tags: sql, temp-tables, declare

I am a novice SQL user and am attempting to perform a loop that displays the values of an object in 1 table referencing a value in a temp table that I created.  Yes, I know there would be an extremely easy way to do this, however I am only looking to display the contents in this loop because I do not have write access to the database I am currently testing this on and eventually the loop will contain a few update statements.  But I want to test the loop now and figure out how to reference the column in my temp table.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @loop INT = 1
DECLARE @max INT

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #temp 
END

SELECT
    0 AS 'row_counter', ID 
INTO
    #temp 
FROM
    Requests
WHERE 
    (Codes_IDs LIKE '%6581%' OR Codes_IDs LIKE '%6597%') 
    AND Codes_IDs LIKE '%6393%' 
    AND Type_ID = 6477 
    AND Codes_IDs NOT LIKE '%6484%'

DECLARE @counter int = 0

UPDATE #temp 
SET @counter = row_counter = @counter + 1
--select * from #temp

SET @max = (SELECT MAX(row_counter) FROM #temp)

WHILE (@loop <= @max)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = (N'Select * from requests where ID in (select ID from #temp where row_counter = @loop)')
    EXEC(@sql)
    SET @loop = @loop +1
END

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
> Must declare the scalar variable "@loop".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
> Must declare the scalar variable "@loop".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
> Must declare the scalar variable "@loop".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
> Must declare the scalar variable "@loop".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
> Must declare the scalar variable "@loop".

As you can see from my errors - for some reason it is not recognizing `@loop` even though I have declared it.

Comment: Variables declared in the outer scope are not accessible in an `EXEC`, so what you're doing here is not possible. It's completely unclear why you think you need dynamic SQL here in the first place -- nothing dynamic is going on in the statement. Better yet, all of this pseudo-cursor code should be tossed out and replaced with set-based logic. About the only circumstance where this sort of looping is needed and unavoidable is if you must call a stored procedure per row, and there is no way of rewriting things or copying the definition, but those cases are rare.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - as stated originally, there is nothing dynamic happening here at the moment.  Once I can figure out how to make the loop work, I will be calling a stored procedure with each row in the temp table.  However for testing purposes (since all I have is write access to this db), I would just like the loop to display the contest of the requests table using the ID stored there.  Yes it is redundant, but I want to ensure the loop works before writing and calling my stored procedure.

Comment: Then the short answer would be "use `sp_executesql` and pass parameters", though the best approach would ultimately still depend on what you're really doing (if you're calling a sproc you don't need `sp_executesql` for example, since you can just call it directly). For *actually* looping through a table's rows you're better off with a cursor, rather than faking one with a counter as you're doing here. Cursors are discouraged for good reasons, but when you're actually working row by row, they're specifically the tool for the job.